# Python3 logging

Tags: python, logging

I'm trying to create my own logger in python 3.6.8 to send output both to stdout and a log file (chosen by date, if the log file doesn't exist yet for today's date it gets created, if there already is a file with the same date just append).

```
from datetime import date
import logging
import logging.handlers
class Log:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def getCleanerLogger(self,moduleName, logFolder, format):
        filename = logFolder+ str(date.today()) + '-log.log'
        handler = logging.FileHandler(filename)
        shandler = logging.StreamHandler()
        shandler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        formatter = logging.Formatter(format)
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        shandler.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger = logging.getLogger(moduleName)
        logger.addHandler(handler)
        logger.addHandler(shandler)
        print("I've been called")
        return logger

import Conf
conf = Conf.configuration()
print(conf['logFolder'] + "   " + conf['logFormat'])
logger = Log()
logger = logger.getCleanerLogger("Log", conf['logFolder'], conf['logFormat'])
logger.info('initializing')
logger.debug('initializing debug')
```

in the json conf file these are the keys I load

```
"logFolder": "log/",
"logFormat": "%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"
```

the log file gets created with the correct logic but there is no logging in either the console or the log file, only the prints go to stdout, no error or exception is raised, I really don't understand why this isn't working. I can only log with logging.root.level('msg') after loading a basiconfig.

Comment: you have to change global level for logger - ie. `logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every handler has own logging level but `logger` has also global logging level which has bigger prioritet so you have to change this level to level which doesn't block handlers - ie.

```
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

---

Mininal working code with few smaller changes.

It doesn't use file with settings so everyone can easily copy it and run it.

```
from datetime import date
import os
import logging
import logging.handlers

class Log:

    def get_cleaner_logger(self, module_name, log_folder, format):
        if not os.path.exists(log_folder):
            os.makedirs(log_folder)

        filename = os.path.join(log_folder, date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-log.log'))
        print(filename)

        logger = logging.getLogger(module_name)
        print('before:', logger.level)
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        print('after:', logger.level)

        formatter = logging.Formatter(format)

        handler = logging.FileHandler(filename)
        handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(handler)

        shandler = logging.StreamHandler()
        shandler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        shandler.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(shandler)

        print("I've been called")

        return logger

conf = {
    "logFolder": "log/",
    "logFormat": "%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"
}

logger = Log()
logger = logger.get_cleaner_logger("Log", conf['logFolder'], conf['logFormat'])
logger.info('initializing')
logger.debug('initializing debug')
```

BTW: I changed some names based on [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I didn't know I had to set the level for logger itself for the handlers to log. I tried following this guide [link](https://realpython.com/python-logging/)

Comment: yee... not a big fan of the snake_case, I finally got rid of the semicolon at the end of statements with python, I'm not ready psychologically to mess it up with underscores xD